# Codeblocks C++ long build times when using ifstream

Tags: c++, build, codeblocks, fstream, ifstream

I have noticed that when I use ifstream in a loop the build times for my C++ projects in Codeblocks dramatically increase.
For example, if I have the following code:

```
int x;
ifstream input("input.txt");
input >> x;
cout << x;
```

Everything works fine. However, if I use ifstream in a loop, the build times always increases to 2 seconds:

```
int numberOfLines;
ifstream input("input.txt");
input >> numberOfLines;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++){
    int temp;
    input >> temp;
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

I've been using Codeblocks for quite some time and have never run into this problem before. However, it appeared after updating my PC to Windows 10. I've failed to find a solution in online forums. Does anybody know how I could fix this problem?

Comment: An issue with the used standard library rather than Codeblocks, by the sound of it.

Comment: *to 2 seconds* - does not seem to be that dramatical...

Comment: My current C++ project takes about 30 minutes to compile from scratch. I wish it was only two seconds.